# How to get Intel integrated-graphic brand string/model num if clGetDeviceInfo() fail?

Tags: opencl, intel, gpgpu

It is known that OpenCL API

```
clGetDeviceInfo(...,CL_DEVICE_NAME,...)
```

can return GPU brand string, for instance "Intel Iris Graphics 5100".

Mostly it works,but on Mac mini(later 2014,os=10.12.5/10.13),it return "Intel Iris" without model num in details. And I tried IOKit,

```
CFDictionaryGetValue(, @"model")
```

return the same, without model num.

Q: Is there any across-platform way to get Intel **GPU** brand string/model num? We known that CPUID instruction can return CPU brand string, is there similar way? Thanks!

The output of clinfo

```
Number of platforms                                  1
Platform Name                                        Apple
Platform Vendor                                      Apple
Platform Version                                     OpenCL 1.2 (Apr    4 2017 19:07:42)
Platform Profile                                     FULL_PROFILE

Platform Name                                        Apple
Number of devices                                      2

Device Name                                     Iris
Device Vendor                                   Intel
Device Vendor ID                                0x1024500
Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 
Driver Version                                  1.2(Apr 22 2017 16:00:44)
Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
Device Type                                     GPU
Device Available                                Yes
Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
Max compute units                               40
Max clock frequency                             1200MHz
```

Comment: What is the output of `clinfo` in terminal?

Comment: @Zindarod thanks for your attention. I edited.